# How to compare field under a different collation?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change collation of a field in to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci MySQL, however it says:

## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'ï¼Žï¼Žï¼Ž.' for key 'username'

I'd like to know all of the rows that have collisions.

I'm imagining something like:

`SELECT x.uid, x.username. y.username, y.uid FROM pre_common_member_archive AS x, pre_common_member_archive AS y 
WHERE x.username COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci = y.username COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci AND x.uid < y.uid;`

However I'm yet to find a syntax that works, the above just goes on forever.

Comment: Ended up duplicating the table, removing the UNIQUE index, changing the collation and doing the comparison.